# Click Button once it loads in jQ

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://m.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/kobe-ix-shoe/pid-973344/pgid-973347

For this website, I'm trying to click the add to cart button once it's finished loading. Will this work? If not, why?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('add-to-cart-btn').load(function () {
        var size_i_want = '%@';
        var how_many = % i;
        var sizesList = document.getElementById('frm-size-select');
        for (var i = 0; i < sizesList.length; i++) {
            if (sizesList.options[i].text == size_i_want) {
                sizesList.selectedIndex = i;
                document.getElementById('quantity-dd').selectedIndex = how_many - 1;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('add-to-cart-btn').click();
    });
```

P.S. excuse me, I'm very noob at js and jq

Answer (score 0):

since youre using jquery you can do:

```
$('#add-to-cart-btn').trigger('click');
```

Comment: That segment of code has been working and continues to work, I just need to know how I can call that once the button is loaded. As of now, (since I'm injecting this into objective C) I'm "adding to cart" once the _entire_ web page is loaded. I think it would be a lot more efficient to perform the function as soon as the element is loaded instead of the entire web page.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood your question, looking at your code again Im wondering why youre using .load() are you making an ajax call?

Comment: I need to call that fn when add-to-cart-btn loads on the web page